# Should Spring Boot auto-configuration classes use the @Configuration annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

Based on my testing, I've found no obvious difference when Spring Boot auto-configuration classes have or don't have the `@Configuration` annotation - if they are configured in `spring.factories` correctly they are loaded regardless of the `@Configuration` annotation.

However, it seems like every custom auto-configuration example and demo uses the `@Configuration` annotation.  Is there a reason all these examples use `@Configuration` (or is it just convention)?  Is there any impact to not using `@Configuration`?

Some examples that use `@Configuration` on auto-configuration classes:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.condition-annotations.class-conditions
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration#creating-a-custom-auto-configuration
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter#1-auto-configuration-classes
- https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-custom-starter/
- https://billykorando.com/2019/12/30/building-a-custom-spring-boot-starter/
- http://www.masterspringboot.com/getting-started-with-spring-boot/spring-boot-quickstarts/how-to-build-a-custom-spring-boot-starter-in-no-time/
- https://github.com/snicoll/spring-boot-master-auto-configuration/blob/main/hornetq-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/hornetq/autoconfigure/HornetQAutoConfiguration.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they should be. The documentation states that [an auto-configuration class should be annotated with `@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.understanding-auto-configured-beans):

> Under the hood, auto-configuration is implemented with standard `@Configuration` classes. Additional `@Conditional` annotations are used to constrain when the auto-configuration should apply. Usually, auto-configuration classes use `@ConditionalOnClass` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotations.

If you do not annotate them with `@Configuration` you are relying upon Spring Framework’s [“lite” @Bean mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts). This changes the behaviour of the auto-configuration classes. It is not guaranteed to work in the future as the implementation does not meet the documented requirements.